# Difficulty setting up validation rules for Firebase datastructure

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on setting up validaton rules for a Firebase data structure, created using the Bolt compiler.

I'm currently having the Bolt statement below:

```
path /sharedEvents/{share} is Boolean[] {
    read() { isMailOfCurrentUser( share ) }
    create() { isOwnerOfEvent( ...) }      //NOT YET CORRECT!
    delete() { isOwnerOfEvent( prior(...) } //NOT YET CORRECT!
}
```

With this, I'm trying to achieve that:

1. Only users having a mail corresponding to the key of 'share' are allowed to read the data (they use this date to retrieve the key of events shared with them.
2. Only the owner of an event is able to add/remove the key for his event to the list of shared events.

This second point is where I'm running into trouble -I'm not able to create the create/delete rules- since I have no idea how to reference the keys of the boolean values in the validation rule...

Example data in Firebase for the above bolt statement:

```
sharedEvents  
        ZW5kc3dhc0BldmVyeW1hMWwuYml6
             -BDKBEvy-hssDhKqVF5w: true
             -FDKBEvy-hsDsgsdsf5w: true
             -ADBEvy-hfsdsdKqVF5w: true
        aXQnc251bWJlcnNAbWExbDJ1LnVz
             -KBEvy-hsDhH6OKqVF5w: true
```

To clarify the needs on this example:
Only user with mail 'ZW5kc3dhc0BldmVyeW1hMWwuYml6' is able to read the three nested childs.
Only the owner of event '-BDKBEvy-hssDhKqVF5w' should be able to create/delete this value. (the same for the other event key/boolean pairs).

My question: is this setup going to work (and how to setup the create/delete rules)? Or is this not going to work and should I rethink/structure the data?

Any help is appreciated!

-----------------OUTPUT JSON FILE------------------------------------------

The question above has been answered, this section is showing the resulting json

```
"sharedEvents": {
      "$share": {
        ".read": "<removed for readability>",
        "$event": {
          ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()",
          ".write": "<removed for readability>"
        }
      }
    },
```

Thanks again for your quick support!

Comment: Hey Peter, I'm not yet clear on your data structure. I think you have a top-level node where the actual event data lives. If so, can you add a snippet of that JSON too?

Comment: I also think you'll have some node that maps from `auth.uid` to the values that you call "mail". Please add that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a nested `path` statement to handle the restriction on the events (the nodes under `/sharedEvents/$mail/$eventid`). I quickly prototyped with this JSON structure:

```
{
  "events": {
    "-ADBEvy-hfsdsdKqVF5w": {
      "name": "Event 1",
      "ownerMail": "aXQnc251bWJlcnNAbWExbDJ1LnVz"
    },
    "-BDKBEvy-hssDhKqVF5w": {
      "name": "Event 2",
      "ownerMail": "aXQnc251bWJlcnNAbWExbDJ1LnVz"
    },
    "-FDKBEvy-hsDsgsdsf5w": {
      "name": "Event 3",
      "ownerMail": "aXQnc251bWJlcnNAbWExbDJ1LnVz"
    },
    "-KBEvy-hsDhH6OKqVF5w": {
      "name": "Event 3",
      "ownerMail": "ZW5kc3dhc0BldmVyeW1hMWwuYml6"
    }
  },
  "sharedEvents": {
    "ZW5kc3dhc0BldmVyeW1hMWwuYml6": {
      "-ADBEvy-hfsdsdKqVF5w": true,
      "-BDKBEvy-hssDhKqVF5w": true,
      "-FDKBEvy-hsDsgsdsf5w": true
    },
    "aXQnc251bWJlcnNAbWExbDJ1LnVz": {
      "-KBEvy-hsDhH6OKqVF5w": true
    }
  },
  "userMails": {
    "peter": "aXQnc251bWJlcnNAbWExbDJ1LnVz",
    "puf": "ZW5kc3dhc0BldmVyeW1hMWwuYml6"
  }
}
```

And came up with these rules:

```
path /sharedEvents/{share} {
    read() { isMailOfCurrentUser(share) }
}

path /sharedEvents/{share}/{event} is Boolean {
    create() { isOwnerOfEvent(event) }
    delete() { isOwnerOfEvent(prior(event)) }
}

isMailOfCurrentUser(share) { true }
getMailOfCurrentUser(uid) { root.ownerMails.uid }
getEventOwnerMail(event) { root.events.event.ownerMail }
isOwnerOfEvent(event) { getMailOfCurrentUser(auth.uid) == getEventOwnerMail(event) }
```

Ignoring any mistakes on my end, this should be the basics of the authorization structure you're looking for.

Comment: Frank, this is great! You helpt me fix an issue that I’ve been struggling with for quite some time :) I was not aware of this possibility to create these ‘double’ paths definitions. Thanks.
The generated rules.json file does however contain a small issue: a boolean .validation statement gets generated for both paths. I have edited my question with the json output since it does not fit in a comment.

Comment: I learned a lot about Bolt while working on the answer, so it was fun! Bolt is awesome. I knew that, but sometimes need a reminder. Oh, and adding your JSON to the question is the right thing to do.